# Router push redirects the page, but not refetch the data in that page

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

$router.push("/") redirects to the Home Page correctly, but Home Page has to fetch new data, but it doesn't. It has the same data what it had previously.

*It can possibly because of creating web history, but I want this functionality later on.*

The home page fetches data from a JSON server.

```
export default {
  name: "Home",
  data() {
    return {
      todos: [],
    };
  },
  components: {
    SingleTodo,
  },
  mounted() {
     fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => (this.todos= data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
  }
```

Which then returns a list to display.

I have added a new page to add data into that JSON server which works fine. After successfully pushing the data I want to redirects to the Home page. Which I am doing like the below snippet.

```
let todo = {
        name: this.name,
        details: this.details,
        completed: false,
      };
      fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(todo),
      })
        .then(this.$router.push("/"))
        .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

This successfully stores the values into the JSON Server and **$router.push("/")** redirects  it to the Home page **but it doesn't refetch the data from the JSON server**.

Router config:

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'
import Home from '../views/Home.vue'
import AddProject from '../views/AddProject.vue'    
const routes = [
      {
        path: '/',
        name: 'Home',
        component: Home
      },
      {
        path: '/add',
        name: 'AddProject',
        component: AddProject
      }
    ]
    
    const router = createRouter({
      history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
      routes
    })
    
    export default router
```

Comment: Show more code of Home Page component - especially the part where you call `fecth`. Router config can be useful too...

Comment: @MichalLevý Added more code parts.

Comment: is there no error in console, warning or something. My be I could help better. the problems I see you called function direct in `mounted()` but you should call them in `methods` and call this.myFunction() inside `mounted()`. and my another advice try using `created()` instead of `mounted()`

Comment: Are you using `<keep-alive>` with `<router-view>` ?

Comment: @WillianBabuu I tried as you told me to call the function from the mounted and it worked. I want you to write this as an answer so that anyone has a somewhat similar issue and finds out. Also, I do not understand the reason for this, an explanation for this will be better for a new learner like me.

Comment: @MichalLevý No, I am not using `<keep-alive>` with `<router-view/>`.  Willian in the comment section mentioned the solution for this. But I do not understand the reason.

Comment: There must be something else because in this case it doesn't matter if you put the code to `mounted()` or `created()` (directly or extract it into it's own `method`). There is no reason you are looking for...

Comment: @MichalLevý Exactly, according to what I read in Vue Docs, this should work exactly the same, but it's working. What I changed is this `mounted() { this.funcFetch(); }, methods: { funcFetch(){ //fetch API }`. Anyways thanks for taking out time for this, much appreciated.

Comment: @MaazRahmanI have updated the answer, I am glad it works, vue life cycle things get confusing sometime. and ofcourse i hope my answer will be marked as accepted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was you used `mounted()` instead of `created()`. sometimes it won't work. Maybe other people will have better explanation to this. you can read more in [official docs](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/options-lifecycle-hooks.html#beforecreate) about vue life cycle

Another thing in your codes use methods instead of wring a function direct in`mounted()` or `created()` your codes should be like this.

```
 methods:{
        getTodo(){
 fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos")
          .then((res) => res.json())
          .then((data) => (this.todos= data))
          .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
}
},
created(){
this.getTodo()
}
```

this make your code look cleaner and will not confuse you in the future

Comment: Sorry but the part comparing `mounted()` and `created()` hooks is just plain wrong...

Comment: Okay I have changed that.

Comment: @WillianBabuu I was doing some random stuff to know the exact reason for it, cause I don't want to build my Vue knowledge with not so clear understanding. I added (in original code) a setTimeout (in my Add Todo page) in `.then()` of fetch API and it worked. So mounted() not clearly needs a function (other than to make the code less confusing). The JSON Server possibly causing the issue, I'll try using another way (probably setting up Firestore for data) and update you accordingly. (Sorry for being this investigative, I hope you understand).

Comment: @Maaz Rahman of course it is the part of learning. We are all learning after all that why we are here. I was happy I could help with something. You dont have to say sorry, I posted answer for you and everyone that may need in the future, not for me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with **JSON Server**.
It helps to spin up a local server and watch a file for data. This is good for development purpose.

But what I noticed is

```
 let todo = {
    name: this.name,
    details: this.details,
    completed: false,
  };
  fetch("http://localhost:3000/todos", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
    body: JSON.stringify(todo),
  })
    .then(this.$router.push("/"))
    .catch((err) => console.log(err.message));
```

in this that JSON Server successfully gets into `.then()` before completely updating the file. I then changed the code

```
.then(setTimeout(() => {
        this.$router.push("/");
      }, 1000))
```

and after redirecting I had all the values that were added.
I can also see it when I opened a browser and the data file side by side, the browser redirects first and then the file updates. *(however, this is not the correct way to check, that's why I added setTimeout)*

Thanks, Everyone for their contribution in the comments.